# Take a screenshot of the foreground window on macOS without requiring click

Tags: macos, screenshot

macOS includes a nifty way to take a screenshot of a window by pressing command shift 4, then space, then click the window you want to screenshot. This includes the nice shadow under the window. I'm in need of some way to trigger this without having to hit space and click the desired window. Ideally, I would set up a keyboard shortcut that would capture the foreground window immediately. How can this be done?

I looked into Grab, and this has the ability to capture a window too, but it still requires you click which window to capture.

Automator includes a Take Screenshot action, but it too requires you click the window to capture.

A timed window capture would work too, but neither Grab nor Automator offer that functionality either.

Comment: Grab has a 10 sec timed capture. Or at least my version does. But it appears to be for whole screen.

Comment: @jmh Grab only has timed screen capture not window, I need the window with the shadow